# RedHat 6 support in WebSphere 6

Tags: websphere, redhat

I have a server side of IBM's WebSphere version 5
and I am running on RedHat version 4, this is working good.

If I will upgrade to WebSphere version 6 and RedHat version 6
Shall I get a problam? or they work well together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's officially supported, no. [WebSphere 6.0 was not supported on RedHat 6](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27007256). In fact, [WebSphere 6.0 is completely out of service](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/support/lifecycle/) anyway.

Independent of the support question, I can't speak to whether that combination actually works at all or reliably.